# working with excel files in php

Tags: php, excel, server-side

What is the best php library to use to with php to read/write and display components of excel files on web based pages?

Comment: Do you want just BIFF .xls files (up to MS Excel 2003), or Office Open XML .xlsx files (Excel 2007 onwards), or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use PHPExcel for writing the files (in fact, I do use it)

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

And you could try

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

for reading but I have no experience with reading Excel files in PHP, only writing them.

Comment: Note that PHPExcel can also read Excel files as well as write them

Comment: It can? Well I'll be buggered, thanks for the info.

Comment: I've tried Phpexcelreader with simple files, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For my mind it is the best library:
[Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected)

Comment: Although Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer can't read Excel files

Comment: What??? Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer read files very well.

Comment: OK! I stand corrected... I've never found any method of accessing data from an existing workbook file using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, but I'm not over-familiar with it. It's not something I would have expected either, given the name, so I've never searched for reading functions that closely in the code.