# Excel charts read and display by PHP - does PHP-ExcelReader support?

Tags: php, excel

My requirement is to display charts present in MS Office excel 2007.

I was looking into PHP-ExcelReader but didn't get any help.

Can someone please help me getting it right by PHP?

Note: I have more than 1 chart in all sheets inside a single excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

yes PHP-ExcelReader supports Excel charts read/write and display by PHP, you can use below code to do this :-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

/*Enable chart read on excel*/
$excel2->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
/*Enable chart read on excel*/

$excel2 = $excel2->load('excelname.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet

/*update cell data if you required */
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', '2');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B7', '1');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', '3');
/*-----------------------------*/

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
/*Enable chart write on excel*/
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
/*Enable chart write on excel*/
$objWriter->save('excelout.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the links in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943551/working-with-excel-files-in-php). They should give you the information you need.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php?rq=1), it is almost identical to yours.

Check out [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/27/reading-and-writing-spreadsheets-with-php) too.